# Binding TextField max size to a Property

Tags: java, javafx

I limit my `TextField` max length like that:

```
int charLimit = 6;
TextField textField = new TextField();
UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> filter = change -> {
    boolean isNotTooLong = change.getControlNewText().length() <= charLimit;
    return isNotTooLong ? change : null;
};
textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(filter));
```

Now, I'd like to bind the charLimit to an `IntegerProperty`.
Here's the draft how I want it to be:

```
public final class LimitedTextField {
        
    public LimitedTextField() {
        TextField internalTextField = new TextField();
        UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> filter = change -> {
            boolean isNotTooLong = change.getControlNewText().length() <= getCharLimit();
            return isNotTooLong ? change : null;
        };
        textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(filter));
    }
    
    //Property
    
    private final IntegerProperty charLimit = new SimpleIntegerProperty
            (LimitedTextField.this, "charLimit");

    public IntegerProperty charLimitProperty() {
        return charLimit;
    }

    public void setCharLimit(int value) {
        charLimit.set(value);
    }

    public int getCharLimit() {
        return charLimit.get();
    }
    
}
```

Is the approach I presented above correct? Will the `TextFormatter` access my property properly? Will it be visible? Maybe should I create a new `TextFormatter` each time `charLimit` property changes?